The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\...\mingw\bin\libopencv_core455.dll
I am attempting to compile a test program with OpenCV using the MinGW GCC compiler. After running CMAKE the program successfully compiles, but when running the program it gives error "The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library c:...\mingw\bin\libopencv_core455.dll" I am using OpenCV Version 4.5.5 using a Mingw library on github (https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build/tree/OpenCV-4.5.5-x64/x64/mingw) to put within the OpenCV files. Do I need to be using another version of OpenCV or what else could cause this issue?
Here is my CMAKELists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(webcam VERSION 0.1.0)
include(CTest)
enable_testing()


find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE-DIRECTORIES})
add_executable(display_image webcam.cpp)

target_link_libraries(display_image ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

Any help is appreciated - Thank You.

Install MinGW and OpenCV from MSYS2, they're guaranteed to be compatible. Also avoid modifying your compiler installation (did you copy opencv dlls over there?), it can be hard to track what you've changed.

You're likely building against a different library to the one being used at runtime

the opencv package maintained by msys2 is https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv
